# Adobe Media Encoder inactivated Tint map colors from After Effects

Tags: after-effects, adobe-media-encoder

I've been generating video uses a template with a Color Control layer that applies to all scenes for a while.

The pre-comp's (template) layers use Tint to map its colors to a the control layer colors.

Preview is correct due to Tint, AE renders the colors perfectly, But AME is no longer render this effect correctly.

[image]

Preview in AE :

[image]

Output after AME render :

[image]

Comment: I don't trust Media Encoder to reliably output complex After Effects projects (or Premiere for that matter). I just render in the application. Not a good answer, hence the comment instead.

Comment: @tomh, Thanks for your comment, The wrong about in-application renderer is the missing support to produce H.264 encoded video. Which is very light compared to the supported.